# Pure Javascript Approach to adding Value of Dynamic Input Fields to Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, validation

**EDIT**

Starting with the solution below, I was able to build out the following, which I could use to create timestamps:

```
// Ready the Chunking Function so we can group entries
function array_chunk( input, size ) {
    for(var x, i = 0, c = -1, l = input.length, n = []; i < l; i++){
        (x = i % size) ? n[c][x] = input[i] : n[++c] = [input[i]];
    }
    return n;
}

// Ready the Zero Prepend-er so dates are always correct
function twoDigitFormat( num ) {
    return ( num.toString().length < 2 ? "0"+num : num ).toString();
}

// Get the Elements, a Nodelist (NL) from the page
var entires = document.getElementsByName('input_252[]');

// Convert NL to Array and Chunk within the Array
for (k = 0; k < entires.length; k++) {
    var entries = array_chunk(entires, 7);
}

// Loop through entries array to get each entry array
for ( i = 0; i < entries.length; i++ ) {
    var entry = entries[i];

    // Loop through each entry array to get the values
    for ( j = 0; j < entry.length; j++ ) {

        var value = entry[j];

        // get all of the parts
        var month = twoDigitFormat(entry[0].value);
        var day = twoDigitFormat(entry[1].value);
        var year = entry[2].value;
        var stime = entry[3].value;
        var stimeperiod = entry[4].value;
        var etime = entry[5].value;
        var etimeperiod = entry[6].value;

    }

    // Make Human Timestamps for each entry array
    var sessionStartString = month + '-' + day + '-' + year + ' ' + stime + '' + stimeperiod;
    var sessionEndString = month + '-' + day + '-' + year + ' ' + etime + '' + etimeperiod;
```

**ORIGINAL**

I am doing validations on form inputs via Javascript. For example,

```
var varName = Form.input_46.value;
if (varName < '2' && varName != ''){                                                                            
    alert("There is a problem with your submission.");
    return (false);                                                                         
}
```

With the HTML:

```
<li id="field_5_91" class="gfield">
    <label class="gfield_label" for="input_5_91">Label Text</label>
    <div class="ginput_container ginput_container_number">
        <input name="input_91" id="input_5_91" type="text" value="" class="small" tabindex="113">
    </div>
</li>
```

... Allows me to check if the number entered into the field meets my parameters when the submit button is clicked.

I also have a input that allows users to click to add additional rows (dynamic):

```
<li id="field_5_252" class="gfield field_sublabel_below field_description_above">
<label class="gfield_label" for="input_5_252_shim">Course Duration</label>
<div class="gfield_description">Enter the information for each class session. Use the only the numeric format for the month and day. Enter the entire year ( EG, 2015 ). Start and End time must use standard digital format ( EG, 1:00, 2:00, 3:00 ). The period - AM or PM - must be capitalized.</div>
<div class="ginput_container ginput_container_list ginput_list">
<input type="text" id="input_5_252_shim" style="position:absolute;left:-999em;" onfocus="jQuery( &quot;#field_5_252 table tr td:first-child input&quot; ).focus();">
<table class="gfield_list">
<colgroup>
    <col id="gfield_list_252_col_1" class="gfield_list_col_odd">
    <col id="gfield_list_252_col_2" class="gfield_list_col_even">
    <col id="gfield_list_252_col_3" class="gfield_list_col_odd">
    <col id="gfield_list_252_col_4" class="gfield_list_col_even">
    <col id="gfield_list_252_col_5" class="gfield_list_col_odd">
    <col id="gfield_list_252_col_6" class="gfield_list_col_even">
    <col id="gfield_list_252_col_7" class="gfield_list_col_odd">
    <col id="gfield_list_252_col_8" class="gfield_list_col_even">
</colgroup>
<thead>
    <tr>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Day</th>
    <th>Year</th>
    <th>Start Time Hour</th>
    <th>Start Time Period</th>
    <th>End Time Hour</th>
    <th>End Time Period</th>
    <th>&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr class="gfield_list_row_odd">
    <td class="gfield_list_cell gfield_list_252_cell1">
        <input type="text" name="input_252[]" value="" tabindex="51">
    </td>
    <td class="gfield_list_cell gfield_list_252_cell2">
        <input type="text" name="input_252[]" value="" tabindex="52">
    </td>
    <td class="gfield_list_cell gfield_list_252_cell3">
        <input type="text" name="input_252[]" value="" tabindex="53">
    </td>
    <td class="gfield_list_cell gfield_list_252_cell4">
        <input type="text" name="input_252[]" value="" tabindex="54">
    </td>
    <td class="gfield_list_cell gfield_list_252_cell5">
        <input type="text" name="input_252[]" value="" tabindex="55">
    </td>
    <td class="gfield_list_cell gfield_list_252_cell6">
        <input type="text" name="input_252[]" value="" tabindex="56">
    </td>
    <td class="gfield_list_cell gfield_list_252_cell7">
        <input type="text" name="input_252[]" value="" tabindex="57">
    </td>
    <td class="gfield_list_icons">   <img src="...blankspace.png" class="add_list_item" title="Add another row" alt="Add a row" onclick="gformAddListItem(this, 0)" onkeypress="gformAddListItem(this, 0)" style="cursor:pointer; margin:0 3px;" tabindex="58">   <img src="...blankspace.png" class="delete_list_item" title="Remove this row" alt="Remove this row" onclick="gformDeleteListItem(this, 0)" onkeypress="gformDeleteListItem(this, 0)" style="cursor: pointer; visibility: visible;" tabindex="59">
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="gfield_list_row_even">
    <td class="gfield_list_cell gfield_list_252_cell1">
        <input type="text" name="input_252[]" value="" tabindex="57">
    </td>
    <td class="gfield_list_cell gfield_list_252_cell2">
        <input type="text" name="input_252[]" value="" tabindex="57">
    </td>
    <td class="gfield_list_cell gfield_list_252_cell3">
        <input type="text" name="input_252[]" value="" tabindex="57">
    </td>
    <td class="gfield_list_cell gfield_list_252_cell4">
        <input type="text" name="input_252[]" value="" tabindex="57">
    </td>
    <td class="gfield_list_cell gfield_list_252_cell5">
        <input type="text" name="input_252[]" value="" tabindex="57">
    </td>
    <td class="gfield_list_cell gfield_list_252_cell6">
        <input type="text" name="input_252[]" value="" tabindex="57">
    </td>
    <td class="gfield_list_cell gfield_list_252_cell7">
        <input type="text" name="input_252[]" value="" tabindex="57">
    </td>
    <td class="gfield_list_icons">   <img src="...blankspace.png" class="add_list_item" title="Add another row" alt="Add a row" onclick="gformAddListItem(this, 0)" onkeypress="gformAddListItem(this, 0)" style="cursor:pointer; margin:0 3px;" tabindex="58">   <img src="...blankspace.png" class="delete_list_item" title="Remove this row" alt="Remove this row" onclick="gformDeleteListItem(this, 0)" onkeypress="gformDeleteListItem(this, 0)" style="cursor: pointer; visibility: visible;" tabindex="59">
    </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</li>
```

**How can I get the values that users enter into an array in order to run validations on the values in pure Javascript?**

I'm trying to replicate the kind of functionality that I have in this jQuery function:

function gf_post_test() {

$output = '.test-output p{margin-bottom:0px;}';

```
$class_sessions = rgpost( 'input_252' );                //get complete array
$each_class_session = array_chunk($class_sessions, 7);  //chunk array on every 7th element
foreach ($each_class_session as $class_session) {       //foreach sub array

    $month = $class_session[0];
    $day = $class_session[1];
    $year = $class_session[2];
    $stime = $class_session[3];
    $stimeperiod = $class_session[4];
    $etime = $class_session[5];
    $etimeperiod = $class_session[6];

    $date = $month .'/'. $day .'/'. $year;
    $start_time = $stime . $stimeperiod;
    $end_time = $etime . $etimeperiod;

    $unix_start = strtotime($date.$start_time);
    $unix_end = strtotime($date.$end_time);

    $user_start = date("m/d/Y H:i:s ", $unix_start);
    $user_end = date("m/d/Y H:i:s ", $unix_end);

    $diff = $unix_start - $unix_end;
    $hours = $diff / ( 60 * 60 );

    if ($hours < 0) $hours = -$hours;               

    $output .= '<p>$unix_start: '. $unix_start .'</p>';
    $output .= '<p>$unix_end: '. $unix_end .'</p>';
    $output .= '<p>$user_start: '. $user_start .'</p>';
    $output .= '<p>$user_end: '. $user_end .'</p>';
    $output .= '<p>$hours: '.$hours.'</p>';

}

$output .= '</div>';

echo $output;
}
```

I have attempted to use Pure Javascript functions like this:

```
var dateTimesArray = new Array();
document.getElementsByName('input_252[]').forEach( function () {
    dateTimesArray.push(this).val());
    }
);
```

But I always return errors - something is undefined, or another thing is not a function. I think that this must be because `document.getElementsByName('input_252[]')` returns a NodeList and not a comma separated string.

Comment: NodeList does not have a function `forEach`. Try `Array.prototype.forEach(getElementsByName('input_252[]'), function(input){ console.log(input.value); })`. Also `dateTimesArray.push(this).val())` something is missing here. I suppose `$` if you are using jQuery

Comment: @Rajesh, when I entered `var entries = document.getElementsByName('input_252[]');` and then ran your suggestion in Console (Chrome), I came back with the error `Uncaught ReferenceError: getElementsByName is not defined(…)`. Do you have a thought about that?

Comment: @Rajesh - I see your remark about the .push line being incorrect. In my other validations, I successfully add a string to an array using that syntax `errorList.push("error message.");`

Comment: @Rajesh - I made another edit above that includes a lot of progress that I've made toward the goal and additional questions.

Comment: Function array_chunk is little confusing. Like you do not need variable l. Var x,n and c can be defined before for. Also, never put multiple question in one question. If you get success with someone's answer but with another error, post another question and mention this question as reference. Also question's length is gone way to much. You should edit and put only that party which is relevant where issue exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByName('input_252[]');
var i;
for (i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
   var input = inputs[i];
   // work with input (validate, etc.)
}
```

Comment: Hey @remdevtec! I got an array that is useful from that operation. `inputs[1]` returns
`<input type=​"text" name=​"input_252[]​" value tabindex=​"52">​` in console. Do you also have insight on what I can do to use the new inputs array to capture the entered values on the form? I'm hoping to recreate the function that I have in jQuery: Chunk array on every 7th element `$each_class_session = array_chunk($class_sessions, 7);` For each sub array `foreach ($each_class_session as $class_session) { ` Get the values to do stuff with (eg) `$month = $class_session[0];`

Comment: From here you get the input HTML object. With this you can get the value (`input.value`) and the `tabindex`, which, if I get it right, by setting `var x = parseInt(input.getAttribute('tabindex')) % 10` you get in `x` the unit digit of tabindex value, which can be used to determine what is the condition (ex. 1 is Month, 2 is Day, etc.). So you can use these values to do your validations.

Comment: Hey @remdevtec, I attempted to get values your way, but had trouble with it. I did find an alternative ( which probably isn't as tidy as what you were doing ) but am still experiencing little issues getting the last stitches in the quilt. Have a look at my update if you have a chance!

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to achieve something like this:

**Note:** *For testing purpose, I have used a common regex to accept only alphabets.*

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/tn5nytk0/)

#### Code

```js
function getRowHTML(id) {
  var HTML = "<div class='row'>" +
    "<input type='text' name='input_252[]' id='" + id + "' />" +
    "<p class='error'></p>" +
    "</div>";

  return HTML;
}

function createHTML() {
  var _html = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < 5;) {
    _html += getRowHTML("txt" + i++);
  }

  document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = _html;
}

function validateInputs() {
  var regex = /^[a-z]+$/gi;

  var inputs = document.getElementsByName("input_252[]");
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(inputs, function(txt) {
    var lblErr = txt.nextSibling;
    lblErr.innerText = regex.test(txt.value) ? "" : "Invalid Value";

  });
}

(function() {
  createHTML();
})()
```

```css
.row {
  width: 90%;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
}
.error {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="content"></div>
<button onclick="validateInputs()">Validate</button>
```