# How do I store and retrieve javascript variables that I have made?

Tags: javascript, arrays, forms

I'm working on a followup question to one I posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34635987/pure-javascript-approach-to-adding-value-of-dynamic-input-fields-to-array), which was resolved.

In my application, I am getting an array of values that are taken from a dynamic field on an input form (Gravity Forms List Field). A testing array that has the same structure can be created this way:

```
var entries = new Array();
entries[0] = new Array( 1, 1, 2016, "9:00", "am", "5:00", "pm");
entries[1] = new Array( 1, 2, 2016, "9:10", "am", "5:10", "pm");
```

From left to right, those values are: month, day, year, start time, star time period, end time, end time period.

Since it is a dynamic input - there could be any number of subarrays on a real submission.

**My goal is to have an array of unix timestamps that I can use to do validations on the form submission. One validation will be 'is the current date more than 6 months past the last submitted date'.**

The following code demonstrates how I am able to produce timestamps.

**I'm looking for a method of adding an unlimited number of timestamps to my array.**

I'm also looking for a method of targeting timestamps, once I have them.

```
// Create an array to collect timestamps
var sessions = new Array();

// Ready the Zero Prepend-er so dates are always correct
function twoDigitFormat( num ) {
    return ( num.toString().length < 2 ? "0"+num : num ).toString();
}

// Loop through entries array to get each entry array
for ( i = 0; i < entries.length; i++ ) {
  var entry = entries[i];

  // Loop through each entry array to get the values
  for ( j = 0; j < entry.length; j++ ) {
    var value = entry[j];

    // get all of the parts
    var month = twoDigitFormat(entry[0]);
    var day = twoDigitFormat(entry[1]);
    var year = entry[2];
    var stime = entry[3];
    var stimeperiod = entry[4];
    var etime = entry[5];
    var etimeperiod = entry[6];
  }

  // Make Human Timestamps for each entry array
  var sessionStartString = month+'-'+day+'-'+year+' '+stime+''+stimeperiod;
  var sessionEndString = month+'-'+day+'-'+year+' '+etime+''+etimeperiod;

  // I'm using moments.js for time handling     
  // Make Session Moments for each timestamp
  var sStartMoment = moment( sessionStartString, "MM-DD-YYYY HH:mm a");
  var sEndMoment = moment( sessionEndString, "MM-DD-YYYY HH:mm a");

  // Make UNIX format moments for each timestamp
  var sStartUnix = sStartMoment.unix();
  var sEndUnix = sEndMoment.unix();

  // Add each UNIX timestamp to the sessions array
  // How do I add arrays with a variable as a key? I don't want to 
  // specify the key. Someone should be able to create 10 entries, 
  // or 20 entries, or .. whatever count.
  sessions[0] = new Array ( sStartUnix );
  sessions[1] = new Array ( sEndUnix ); 
}

// Get the current time (and as UNIX)
var now = moment();
var nowUnix = now.unix();

// Loop through sessions
for ( l = 0; l < sessions.length; l++ ) {
    var session = sessions[l];  

  // How do I get things out of the array of timestamps? 
  // My current code results in session[key] being UNDEFINED?
  var lastSession = session[session.length-1];      

}

// Do stuff - like math, to run validations
// I know this isn't correct, but the idea will be to get
// a difference in hours
var lastNowDiff = nowUnix - lastSession;

if ( lastNowDiff > 4320 ) {
  alert('The submission date must be within 6 months.');
}
```

I have it [running in a Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jryven/ovc2f1b7/47/) if you have a moment to check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use array's push method.

Example:

```
var entries = new Array();
entries.push(new Array( 1, 1, 2016, "9:00", "am", "5:00", "pm"));
```

You can add any number of arrays like this.

Complete Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jryven/ovc2f1b7/

Comment: Thanks @sundar, that was a great lead. I updated my Fiddle to reflect the suggestion. By using `sessions.push(new Array (sStartMoment, sEndMoment));` on line 49, I was able to start putting my entries in the desired array (submissions). I'm still struggling with a method to get differences between dates/timestamps that are useful. https://jsfiddle.net/jryven/ovc2f1b7/

Comment: why cant u try moment library which is awesome library for date comparison and date related stuffs instead of using the native date?

Comment: I do have moment.js loaded up. Perhaps I'm not using it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Use the JavaScript `Date` object for parsing and validating.